# OSX: Setting the right resolution on displays

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, resolution

I have a 2017 13" MacBook Pro. I connected 2x 27" monitors with 2560 × 1440 resolution. It's connected with HDMI with 2 dongles, one on each USB C port. Lid closed, I have enough with the two screens :)

The first monitor works fine, it takes the default resolution (2560×1440). However the second one only gets 1920×1080 then it is scaled to 2560×1440. This scaling is only applied *sometimes* and it is not shown in the scaling options.

Is it possible to run both monitors at full resolution ?
If not, how can I set the scaled resolution on the second monitor correctly ?

[image]

Comment: idk that particular display, but quite often the generic fix is to get rid of HDMI & use DisplayPort instead.

Comment: What @tetsujin said, but in the meantime I hear SwitchResX might help https://www.madrau.com

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue and switching to display port dongles fixed it for me.